# auto reference to a vector in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an auto reference to a vector:

```
auto &myVector = solution->myVector;
```

where solution->myVector is a public member, a vector of some objects.

If I later do this in the code:

```
myVector = someOtherVector;
```

will solution->myVector change?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is what references are. Aliases for something else.

Comment: As kbok writes below, a reference is the referent so his rephrasing of the assignment using the operator =() is what will happen.  See also http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr110.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course, as it would happen if the public member was an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This will call `myVector.operator=()` which is, in fact, `solution->myVector.operator=()`.